# MongoDb update a route with two id's?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, backbone.js

My models on the front end are not saving. `:tid` is the team id and `:pid` is player id.

```
router.put('/api/players/:tid/:pid', player.update);

update: function(req, res) {
    models.Player.update({ _id: req.params.pid }, function(err, player) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error: 'Player not found.'});
        } else {
            console.log(player);
        }
    })
} // obviously looks a bit illogical, but not sure what to do here 100%
```

Right now I am just using a static team ID in my backbone collection.

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
    PlayerModel = require('../models/player');

module.exports = PlayersCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:  PlayerModel,
    url: '/api/players/545d1d72f7895d00008e2f43'
});
```

So basically that grabs the players with team_id `545d1d72f7895d00008e2f43` but it also wants to post to that route with the players id, which is why my route above requires, `:tid/:pid`

I am just not sure what my mongoDB update function should look like to properly update the model on the server.

Comment: Can you be more precise in what exactly the problem is? Is is the database on the server that is not being updated or the corresponding Backbone model on he frontend? The first thing I've noticed immediately is that you're passing only the query object to the `models.Player.update` method without the updated object object itself (should be `models.Player.update({ _id: req.params.pid }, {...updated model...}`, function(err, player) { ... }).

Comment: I am not getting any console errors, when I refresh the page or check the database nothing gets updated. Initially I was getting a 404 because the route wasn't setup properly, but apparently it is setup fine now since I am not getting a 404.

Comment: The front end is fine, it updates in memory but when the page reloads the database has not been updated

Answer (score 0):

Okay I forgot this was an old gotcha, I had ran into this a while back. I had to add `req.body`.

```
update: function(req, res) {
    models.Player.update({ _id: req.params.pid }, req.body, function(err, player) {
        if (err) {
            res.json({error: 'Player not found.'});
        } else {
            res.json(player);
        }
    });
}
```